# Evaluate $ \frac{1}{(q)_\infty} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{\frac{m^2}{2}} (-q^{-\frac{1}{2}}x)^m y^m(q^{1-m}y^{-1};q)_\infty $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, integer-partitions, theta-functions, q-series

This identity is taken from a physics paper [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07654)] stated without proof, on page 43.

$$ \frac{1}{(q)_\infty} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{\frac{m^2}{2}} (-q^{-\frac{1}{2}}x)^m y^m(q^{1-m}y^{-1};q)_\infty
= \frac{(xy;q)_\infty(qx^{-1}y^{-1};q)_\infty}{(x;q)_\infty}
\tag{$*$}$$

This formula is new and interesting and probably correct.  I don't know a good starting point.  While this is a $q$-series, there are *two* deformation paramters $x$ and $y$.  It may help to recall some definitions:

- $\displaystyle \prod_{n \geq 0} \big( 1 - q^n x \big) =: (x;q)_\infty $ this is the $q$-Pochhammer [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol)
- $\displaystyle \prod_{n = 0}^{k-1} \big(1 - q^n x \big) =: (x;q)_k$ this is the $q$-Pochhammer [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol)

The symbol $(q;q)_k$ gets its own abbreviation $(q)_k$ but it's very similar.

- $\displaystyle (q)_\infty  := (q;q)_\infty = \prod_{n \geq 1} (1 - q^n) $
- $\displaystyle (q)_k  := (q;q)_k = \prod_{n=1}^k (1 - q^n) $

These series are likely to "converge" as elements of $\mathbb{Z}[q^{\frac{1}{2}}][[x^{\pm 1}, y^{\pm 1}]]$, but do these also converge analytically?  This might not converge for any $q \in \mathbb{C}$.

In order to check the equivalence, we might start with some partial fraction decomposition:

$$ \frac{1}{(x;q)_\infty} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(q;q)_n} $$

I also wonder what the RHS of $(*)$ is counting.

Comment: It looks like a form of Jacobi triple product

Comment: A book that has some similar identities to this is Berndt's "Number Theory in the Spirit of Ramanujan". Also, the questions about convergence are typically not regarded as important when dealing with $q$-analogues. These types of power series are considered in a strictly formal manner in most cases, As mentioned above me, the Jacobi triple product formula may be a good first identity to check.

Comment: This reminds me of [Andrew's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_conjecture#q-Dyson_conjecture). Admittedly this is very different from Andrew's conjecture though. With the notation of the link, it's as if it is $n=2$ ($x_1=x, x_2=y^{-1}$) but $a_1=a_2=\infty$ case if that even makes any sense.

Comment: Have you tried the q-Zeilberger algorithm?